# How to display a message when no number is entered in the Number field in Android Emulator, Android Studio?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int randomNumber;

    public void guess(View view)
    {
        EditText numberEntered = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enteredNumber);
        String numberEnteredString = numberEntered.getText().toString();
        int numberEnteredInteger = Integer.parseInt(numberEnteredString);

        String message = "";
        if (numberEnteredInteger == randomNumber ) {
            message = "Correct Guess";
        }
        else if(numberEnteredInteger < randomNumber) {
            message = "Too Low!";
        }
        else if (numberEnteredInteger > randomNumber){
            message = "Too High!";
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I'm a beginner in JAVA, ANDROID STUDIO. My Task is to ask a user to enter a number which should match my random number. If user's entered number matches my random number it should display the message as mentioned in the sample code.

The below code is running for all the three cases mentioned in the if statements. How to write a code for displaying a message when no number is entered in the Number field?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
boolean error = false;
String message = "";
int numberEnteredInteger;
try {  numberEnteredInteger = Integer.parseInt(numberEnteredString); 
}
Catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   error = true;
}
if (error) {
    message = "Invalid Number"
}
else if (numberEnteredInteger == randomNumber ) {
```

...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Toast`:

```
Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "need number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Or you can use `setError`:

```
edittext.setError("need number")
```